# What is the status of Jungian psychology in the XXI-century?

Tags: history-of-psychology, epistemology

Now Cognitive-Behavioral therapy seems the main kind of therapy practised all over the world, which comes along with the claim of CBT techniques have been proved to work scientifically, meanwhile old psychoanalytic techniques are in the limbo of pseudoscience. Can anyone still rightfully practice Jungian psychoanalysis in their practice?